TypeScript Type Mismatch: Handling Already Declared Promise Wrapper in Return Type
I have this code in typescript:
type Chain = 'eth'

export type ApiMethods = {
  getToken: {
    path: 'tokens/'
    (args: {
      chain: Chain
      tokenAddress: EthereumAddress
    }): string
  }

  getRank: {
    path: 'rank/wallets/'
    (): string
  }
}

type MethodParams<K extends keyof ApiMethods> = Parameters<ApiMethods[K]>[0]

type Api = {
  [K in keyof ApiMethods]: MethodParams<K> extends undefined
    ? {path: ApiMethods[K]['path'], (): Promise<ReturnType<ApiMethods[K]>>}
    : {path: ApiMethods[K]['path'], (args: MethodParams<K>): Promise<ReturnType<ApiMethods[K]>>}
}

type ApiParameters<K extends keyof Api> = Parameters<Api[K]>[0]

type ApiPath<K extends keyof Api, T = ApiParameters<K>> = T extends {chain: Chain} 
    ? `${Api[K]['path']}${T['chain']}/`
    : `${Api[K]['path']}`

type Payload<K extends keyof Api> = Omit<Parameters<Api[K]>[0], 'chain'>

export type ApiClientOptions = {
  apiRoot?: string
}

class ApiClient {
  private readonly options: Required<ApiClientOptions>

  constructor(options: ApiClientOptions = {}) {
    const defaultOptions = {
      apiRoot: 'https://api.com/',
    };
    this.options = { ...defaultOptions, ...options };
  }

  private async callApi<K extends keyof Api>(path: ApiPath<K>, payload: Payload<K>): ReturnType<Api[K]> {

  }
}

The Api type wraps the function return type into a Promise.
The problem is that within the callApi function I get the error:
 The return type of an async function or method must be the global Promise<T> type. Did you mean to write 'Promise<ReturnType<Api[K]>>'?

Why does this happen if the return type of the Api type are already wrapped in a Promise? How can I fix the issue?

As far as I can tell, async methods need to explicitly return Promise; if you try to alias it too much you get errors, because the compiler can't accept certain things (like Promise<void> & SomeOtherType) even though they are assignable to Promises (e.g., https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/35856).  You can write Promise<Awaited<ReturnType<Api[K]>>> as shown in this playground link. Does that fully address the q? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

@jcalz Yes, everything makes sense. Then, would your reckon that the API type is not necessary since the only thing it does is Promisify the function return types?

You've got a lot of stuff going on in that example, so only you could say that API is or is not necessary. It's up to you. I'll write an answer when I get a chance.

TypeScript requires that an async function explicitly returns the global Promise type. It's a little stricter than normal because async functions cannot return a custom subtype of Promise (see microsoft/TypeScript#35856). The check seems to be tighter than it needs to be; your generic type ReturnType<Api[K]> isn't syntactically required to be a Promise (it depends on a higher-order analysis of Api which the compiler doesn't seem to do), so it complains.
The most straightforward way around this would be to wrap your type with Promise<Awaited<⋯>>. If your type was already a Promise then it shouldn't change anything (because the Awaited type unwraps Promises). If not, it will make it a Promise:
private async callApi<K extends keyof Api>(
  path: ApiPath<K>,
  payload: Payload<K>
): Promise<Awaited<ReturnType<Api[K]>>> {⋯}

Playground link to code
